# Meteor app not inserting elements into collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform, meteor-collections

I am learning Meteor JS and followed a tutorial to build a menu builder shopping list. I am trying to add some features to it. I added one feature successfully, but now I am trying to create an organization feature where users can join an organization and see all shopping lists related to that organization. The first step is to allow for adding an organization by users.

The form appears, and I was able to insert in to the database from the console, but when I use autoform the objects are not being inserted into the database.

I recently upgraded from Meteor 1.3 to 1.4. I don't believe that is an issue since all of the other forms on the app are inserting properly still.

I have a feeling it has something to do with subscribe/publish, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**HTML- neworganization.html**

```
        <template name='NewOrganization'>
    <div class='new-organization-container'>

        <i class='fa fa-close'></i>

          {{#autoForm collection='Organizations' id='insertOrganizationForm'  type='insert'}}
<div class='form-group'>
      {{> afQuickField name='organization'}}
      </div>
      <div class='form-group'>
      {{> afQuickField name='members'}}
      </div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  {{/autoForm}}

    </div>


</template>
```

**organizations.html**

```
<template name='Organizations'>
<h3>Your Organizations</h3>
{{#if $.Session.get 'newOrganization'}}
        {{> NewOrganization }}
{{else}}
<button class='btn btn-organization btn-primary'>Add an Organization</button>
<button class='btn btn-join'>Join an Organization</button>
<button class='btn btn-deny'>Leave an Organization</button>
{{/if}}
<section class='organization-list'>
        {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{#each organizationList}}
            {{> OrganizationItem}}
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <p>Loading...</p>
    {{/if}}
```

**JS- organizations.js**

```
Template.Organizations.onCreated(function() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('organizations');
  });
});

Template.Organizations.helpers({
    organizations()  {
        return Organizations.find({});
    }
});


Template.Organizations.events({
      'click .btn-organization': () => {
        Session.set('newOrganization', true);
      }
});

Template.NewOrganization.helpers({
    organizationList: () => {

      var organizationItems = Organizations.find({});

        return organizationItems;
    }
});
```

**newOrganization.js**

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('organizations');
} 
Template.NewOrganization.events ({
    'click .fa-close': function () {
        Session.set('newOrganization', false);
    }
});
```

**collections/organizations.js**

```
    import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);


Organizations = new Mongo.Collection('organizations');

Organizations.allow({
    insert: function(userId){
        return !!userId;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc){
        return !!userId;
    }
});


OrganizationSchema = new SimpleSchema ({
    organization: {
        label: "Organization Name",
        type: String
    },
    id: {
        label: "ID",
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    members: {
        type: Array
    },
        "members.$": Object,
        "members.$.name": String,
        "members.$.role": String,
          inOrganization: {
            type: Boolean,
            defaultValue: true,

            autoform: {
                type: 'hidden'
            }
      },

    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "CreatedAt",
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        },
        autoValue: function() {
            return new Date();
        }
    }
});

Meteor.methods({
    deleteOrganizations: function(id) {
        Organizations.remove(id);
    }
});

Organizations.attachSchema(OrganizationSchema);
```

Comment: Apologies since I don't remember too much of autoforms at the given time. But can you try two things: 1. ```{{#autoForm collection=Organizations ...}}``` 2. ```{{#autoForm collection='Organizations' schema='OrganizationSchema' ...}}``` and see if either of the two wook? Also, can you check to see if autoform is throwing any error in the browser console? You can enable more debug level logs by having this somewhere in your schema file: ```SimpleSchema.debug = true```

Comment: blueren, Thanks for the suggestions. The first example suggested caused the form not to appear. The second one had no effect. I appreciate you letting me know about the debug  method. Unfortunately, it did not show any errors. It was such a small section in the documentation, that I had overlooked it before.

Comment: I figured out the problem. In my schema I was manually inputting the id where I should have just let it automitcally let it generate. I erased that part of my schema and it inserted just fine.

Comment: Good to know  you solved the issue. Maybe you can post it as an answer and mark this question as answered. :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that I could answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way the Schema was designed. I had inserted an id into the schema. My reasoning was that I wanted to have a way to add and remove members from an organization. What I did not take into account was that Mongo autogenerates an id for database object and by designing my schema in this way, I was creating a conflict. I removed the id from my schema and removed the problem.

Here is the new collections/organizations.js file:

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);

Organizations = new Mongo.Collection('organizations');

Organizations.allow({
    insert: function(userId){
        return !!userId;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc){
        return !!userId;
    }
});


OrganizationSchema = new SimpleSchema ({
    organization: {
        label: "Organization Name",
        type: String
    },
    members: {
        type: Array
    },
        "members.$": Object,
        "members.$.name": String,
        "members.$.role": String,

          inOrganization: {
            type: Boolean,
            defaultValue: true,

            autoform: {
                type: 'hidden'
            }
      },

    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "CreatedAt",
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        },
        autoValue: function() {
            return new Date();
        }
    }
});

Meteor.methods({
    deleteOrganizations: function(id) {
        Organizations.remove(id);
    }
});

SimpleSchema.debug = true;

Organizations.attachSchema(OrganizationSchema);
```